# Why can't the Doctor sense the other Timelords?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

So at some point in the new *Doctor Who*, The Doctor mentions that he would be able to sense whether or not there were any other Timelords across time and space. However, throughout the series, he doesn't sense any of these Timelords and part-Timelords:

> The Master, Jenny, River Song, The Doctor-Donna, Rassilon and his council, etc.

Is there any reason for this besides "timey-wimey" or "Doctor Who has no canon"?

Also, can anyone give me the episode name and the exact quote?

Comment: Well, Rassilon and Council may have been because they were in the time-lock. The others I have no speculation on. Good Q tho.

Comment: The only episode I can think of where he mentions being able to sense other time lords is "The Doctor's Wife"; where he senses the presence of time lords in the pocket universe (but is disappointed by what he finds). The quote you're looking for might be found in that episode.

Comment: Wasn't he following a stolen Timelord message cube in that episode?

Comment: I would guess that the quote is from Christopher Eccleston's season, probably in response to some question from Rose.

Comment: The master was hidden in human form at the end of he universe, Rassilon was timelocked, river is not a time lord, Jenny is a clone and doctor Donna is a human-timelord meta crisis

Comment: @CarlSixsmith The Master became a Timelord again (he was able to regenerate).

Comment: @RogueJedi and at that point he became aware of him

Comment: @CarlSixsmith But if he can sense Timelords across time, he should have sensed his existence earlier.

Comment: @RogueJedi no because his time stream timey wimey hadn't synced up. He also can't detect all the time lords in the pocket universe

Comment: Can *youuu* sense other *huuumans*??

Comment: No. And I can't regenerate either. It's almost as if different species can do different things or something.

Comment: @sqb That question is about why the Doctor couldn't recognize someone. My question is about why the Doctor couldn't sense any of the existing Timelords. I feel they are different enough.

Comment: @RogueJedi The older *question* is more specific, but its *answer* looks like it covers everything you're asking about and more.

Comment: What @randal'thor said.

Comment: Jenny isn't a Time Lord. She only has one heart, as was emphasized in the episode.

Answer (score 11):

I believe that was from **The Sound of Drums**, Series 3, Episode 12.

> **DOCTOR**: There it is. That rhythm, it's everywhere, ticking away in the
>   subconscious.
>   **MARTHA**: What is it, mind control?
>   **DOCTOR**: No, no,
>   no, no, no. It's subtler than that. Any stronger and people would
>   question it. But contained in that rhythm, in layers of code, Vote
>   Saxon. Believe in me. Whispering to the world. Oh, yes! That's how he
>   hid himself from me, ***because I should have sensed there was another
>   Time Lord on Earth.*** I should have known way back. The signal cancelled
>   him out.

Which also covers why he couldn't sense the Harold Saxon instance of the Master.

Earlier this is mentioned in the episode, **Dalek**, Series 1, Episode 6

> **ROSE**: The Dalek survived. Maybe some of your people did too.
>   **DOCTOR**: I'd know. In here. (his head) Feels like there's no one.

Comment: That's a good clear example, but I think the first mention of this concept of a psychic awareness of any other Time Lords was in *Dalek* from Series 1, where Rose said "The Dalek survived. Maybe some of your people did too" and the Doctor replied "I'd know. In here. (his head) Feels like there's no one."

Comment: Missy no longer heard the signal, right? So why couldn't the Doctor sense her?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72349/why-didnt-the-doctor-or-clara-recognize-missy-right-away for a detailed breakdown on the inconsistencies of this ability and a possible explication to the Missy situation

Comment: It's possible that Time Lords can hide from each other, and that the Doctor couldn't since Missy because she didn't want to be sensed. The Master was the first Time Lord to be shown to deny regeneration, so why not deny "Time Lord psychic radar detection" as well?